# Layout won't change to layout-land version

Tags: android, layout, orientation, landscape

I just learned about changing layouts using a duplicate layout in a different folder called 'layout-land'.

I simply copied over the entire code from the original layout, and was careful not to make typos. In my manifest there is nothing which indicates I want to handle the orientation code myself.

Still, when I run the application and I change to orientation from the default portrait to landscape mode, the layout refuses to change to the identically named layout in the 'layout-land' folder, which has a different color background to make sure. By the way, I am using an Emulator, for platform 4.4. Please also note that I am a beginner.

If anyone could suggest what could be going wrong, I'd appreciate it!

*manifest file*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.MB2Assignment.assignment"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name="com.MB2Assignment.assignment.Menu"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.MB2Assignment.assignment.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.MB2Assignment.assignment.Counter"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.COUNTER" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

         <activity
            android:name="com.MB2Assignment.assignment.Settings"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SETTINGS" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.MB2Assignment.assignment.prefs"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PREFS" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

         <activity
            android:name="com.MB2Assignment.assignment.about"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">           
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ABOUT" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

         <activity
            android:name="com.MB2Assignment.assignment.Graphics"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.GRAPHICS" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

         <activity
            android:name="com.MB2Assignment.assignment.GFXSurface"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.GRAPHICSSURFACE" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

         <activity
            android:name="com.MB2Assignment.assignment.Sound"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SOUND" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


    </application>



</manifest>
```

*layout-xml file*

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/blue"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button_MenuToCounter"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:text="MENU"
        android:textSize="30dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_MenuToCounter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:text="Counter" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_MenuToGraphics"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button_MenuToCounter"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="The Falling Man" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_MenuToGraphics2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button_MenuToGraphics"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="The Following Man" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imagebutton_settings"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button_MenuToGraphics2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/settings" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Could you post some details from the app's manifest?

Comment: If you switch layout/x.xml and layout-land/x.xml do you see the different background color? Perhaps the layouts aren't defined right. You may want to post those too.

Comment: Do you use this _android:configChanges="orientation"_ in AndroidManifest when you declare the activity? It can cause that you described.

Comment: I edited my code into the original post.

Comment: MazeHatter, what do you mean, 'defined right'? I added my layout code as well, right under the Manifest code. I use the exact same code for the landscape version of the layout.

Comment: @Turbosheep : u can check it on real device and double check what T.V. told

Comment: @Turbosheep It is a OS bug, If your are using Android4.4 emulator. See "Jstn" answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure there's nothing similar to this in your manifest more specifically in the activity you want to show/control

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

if you have, remove it.

Also make sure your xml files have the same name

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry! I guess I did it? Don't remember clicking anything. I 'upvoted' it again. Anywya, as to your answer, I don't seem to have anything like 'screenOrientation' in my xml files. They are identically named as well, see this screenshot: http://puu.sh/6rPD4.png

Comment: and how about your manifest file? do you have something similar to that in the activity declaration? try to change the Android API to a lower one or try it in a real device, maybe the solution is on @jstn answer.

Answer (score 1):

Its actually a bug in the Android 4.4 emulator. You may track the issues which are already filed regarding the orientation change bug...
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61671

Answer (score 0):

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

should not be in the RelativeLayout attributes

Comment: Ah right, I added that after hours of searching on the net and trying things out. It still doesn't work without that statement, sadly, but thank you.